# How to remove ^M in a Hive table row?

Tags: hive

I get data from upstream as csv file and create Hive table on top of it. Now some of the csv file contains control M character in few rows/columns. For e.g. 3 column data is shown below with control M character

```
abc^M,def,ghi
jkl,mno^M,pqr
```

Now I load data into Hive table using `LOAD DATA INPATH '/path/to/file' INTO TABLE mytable` Since above data contains control M Hive considers it as line break and breaks that row into new line so above data in Hive table returns 4 row count instead of 2.

I tried using `regex_replace(mycol,'[\x01-\x1A]',"\\")` to replace all control characters including control M with \ and it works but it leaves behind \ sign for e.g. `abc^M` will become `abc\` I don't want to change the data is there any better way to do this? I am not sure even custom serde will help in this case. I am new to Hive.

Comment: Why not use `regex_replace(mycol,'[\x01-\x1A]','')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to replace `^M` by `\` and hence it is showing up in your final result. Replace it by empty string. Something like:

```
regexp_replace(mycol, '[\x01-\x1A]', '')
```

On the other side, it is a good idea to cleanup the file first and then upload it in HDFS.

Replace `^M` from the source file and then upload will make things better.

Sample code:

```
$ tr -d '\015' < /path/to/file/file1 > /tmp/file1
$ LOAD DATA INPATH '/tmp/file1' INTO TABLE mytable
```

There are other ways to remove `^M` from the file:

- http://www.theunixschool.com/2011/03/different-ways-to-delete-m-character-in.html
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/sed-remove-m-and-line-feeds-under-unix-linux-bsd-appleosx/

Answer (score 1):

Just similar to the way to remove ^M in Vim like :%s/\r/, in Hive you can try to remove it by

`regexp_replace(mycol, '\r', '')`

For a common way to remove special characters  in Hive, I usually do this:

`regexp_replace(mycol, '\r|\t|\n', '')`